# incompatible types: int cannot be converted to java.lang.String ошибка

Tags: java, таймер

Подскажите пожалуйста появляется ошибка в это месте, не знаю как исправить
/**
* Запускает часы
*/
public void start(){
ActionListener listener = new TimerPrinter();
Timer t = new Timer (interval, listener);
t.start();
}

```
public class InnerClassTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TalkingClock clock = new TalkingClock(1000, true);
        clock.start();

        //выполнять программу до тех пор, пока пользователь
        //не щелкнет на кнопке OK
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Quit program?");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

public class TalkingClock {
    private int interval;
    private boolean beep;

    /**
     * Конструирует "говорящие часы"
     * @param interval Интервал между сообщениями (в миллисекундах)
     * @param beep Истинно, если часы должны издавать звуковой сигнал
     */
    public TalkingClock(int interval, boolean beep){
        this.interval = interval;
        this.beep = beep;
    }
    /**
     * Запускает часы
     */
    public void start(){
        ActionListener listener = new TimerPrinter();
        Timer t = new Timer (interval, listener);
        t.start();
    }

    public class TimerPrinter implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            Date now = new Date();
            System.out.println("At the tone, the time is " + now);
            if (beep) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Это вы сами придумали, что конструктор `Timer` принимает аргументы интервал и ActionListener или где-то прочитали? [Документация](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) с вами не согласна

Comment: Это пример с книги Библиотека профессионала